# Deprecated: Error in line 616

Tags: wordpress, line, deprecated

I just tried to enter my site and start showing this error message:

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /opt/php54/lib/php/XML/Parser.php on line 616

it´s a Wordpress, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Did you upgrade PHP on your server?

Comment: Look at the code that the error points you to, and fix it?